# For in Django template

Tags: django, list, for-loop, django-templates

Two days with Django and Python.

```
   {% for 15 in episode.name %}
       <li><a href="{{ STATIC_URL }}video/S{{numberSeason}}01.webm">{{episode.name}}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
```

How make episode.name.1, episode.name.2 ... episode.name.15 in list?

Comment: what is the structure of episode.name ? Is it a list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `{{episode.name}}` is an iterable, you need to do it this way:

```
{% for name in episode.name %}
   <li><a href="{{ STATIC_URL }}video/S{{numberSeason}}01.webm">{{name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```